# Есть ли функция, перемешивающая элементы массива произвольным образом?

Tags: c++

Есть ли функция, перемешивающая элементы массива произвольным образом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть, называется [random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/).
Пример использования:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); 
    std::random_shuffle(arr, arr + arr_size);
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно. Находится в stl, [random_shuffle](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/). Ей нужен итератор на начало и конец (массив может это предоставить) и функция рандомизации.